# accessing child node in firebase database (Android)

Tags: android, firebase

this is how my database looks

```
mainAlbum
     Album1
        id: ""
        image_name: ""
        image_path: ""
        pic1
           id: ""
           image_name: ""
           image_path: ""
        pic2
           id:  ""
           image_name: ""
           image_path: ""
```

i was able to access the image_name and image_path under Album1, but i dont know how to access pic 1 and pic 2. There are more than 1 album and i can access them all, and each album will have many pictures

Here is the code i used to access the database.

```
   private void getData(){
        firebaseDatabaseInstance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

        // get reference to 'users' node
        booksInstance = firebaseDatabaseInstance.getReference("mainAlbum");

        booksInstance.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                setData(dataSnapshot);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                // Failed to read value
                Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
            }
        });

    }

    List<List<String>> booksInfo;
    List<String> temp;
    private void setData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
        booksInfo = new ArrayList<>();
        for (DataSnapshot alert: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            temp = new ArrayList<>();
            Log.d("image_name", (String) alert.child("image_name").getValue());
            Log.d("id", (String) alert.child("id").getValue());
            Log.d("image_path", (String) alert.child("image_path").getValue());
            temp.add((String) alert.child("image_name").getValue());
            temp.add((String) alert.child("id").getValue());
            temp.add((String) alert.child("image_path").getValue());
            booksInfo.add(temp);
        }

        if(booksInfo.size() > 0){
            setGridView();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "No data Found.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Better you normalize your album

Comment: you can use a simple while loop like `while(alert.child("pic"+n).exists())` and n starts at 1 and increments each time

Comment: @Linxy where do i put this line using the code above to access pics?

Comment: inside your for loop I assume

Comment: i tried that. it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your firebase database structure, accessing the pic from the album can only be done by accessing each pic individually.

If you want to access the pictures as a list, you probably should make your structure like

```
mainAlbum
 Album1
    id: ""
    image_name: ""
    image_path: ""
    pics
        pic1
           id: ""
           image_name: ""
           image_path: ""
        pic2
           id:  ""
           image_name: ""
           image_path: ""
```

and then you can access the pictures by getting the "pics" child

Comment: and then just use this line of code to access it    booksInstance = firebaseDatabaseInstance.getReference("mainAlbum").child("pics"); ?

Comment: i was able to access it on iOS with the structure provided above so i am sure there is a way to do it on android